# How to calculate the angle between two vectors in high-dimensional space?

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate the angle (or the slope) of the line that connects two points $a,b \in R^N$. By high, I mean $N>3$.

How can I do this?

Also, can I describe this line with only an angle, or do i need a bigger data structure like a Quaternion or something? I want the direction of the line, the magnitude is not important.

And I'm trying to do this in MATLAB, so I would really appreciate a code example.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: an angle is not enough to describe a line in $R^N$.

Comment: You need at least $N-1$ numbers to describe a line in $\Bbb R^N$.  If you want, you can make these numbers "angles" of some sort.

Comment: Ok, so how do I obtain that N-1 dimensional vector?

Comment: There are many $N-1$ dimensional vectors we can use, depending on how you want to describe the line.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest way to do it is to take the vector $b - a$ and say that it's the line "in the direction of $b-a$".

Comment: I'm interested in the direction of this line. So I thought the best way would be to use the angles. Maybe the angles of the projections of the line on N axes? Edit: hehe yes that would be easy. However I want a numeric descriptor in order to use in a pattern recognition problem.

Comment: Well so the one problem you get by directly using $b-a$ is that now the same line has multiple aliases.  The way you fix that is you take $b-a$, normalize it (divide it by its length), and multiply it by $-1$ if the first entry is negative.  Now, each line gets exactly one alias.

Comment: Another common trick with $b-a$ is to divide it by the first entry (or last entry, which is more common) so that the first entry is a $1$ (you'll have to handle the case where the first entry is zero separately).  This gives you the usual presentation of something that we math folk refer to as "projective space".

Comment: MATLAB question: do you write vectors as row-vectors or column-vectors?

Comment: I prefer columns as observations, rows as dimensions. So columns.

Comment: So what exactly is it that you were going to do with these "angles" if you find enough to describe the line?  I want to know if I have to be careful with how I choose them.

Comment: As I said, I have multiple samples that contain these shapes, and I want to represent them with these angles and train a pattern classifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to calculate the angle between two vectors (say, $u$ and $v$) in high-dimensional space, the formula is 
$$
A = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{u \cdot v}{\|u\|\|v\|}\right)
$$
Where $u\cdot v$ denotes the dot product.  In MATLAB:

```
A = acos((u'*v)/(norm(u)*norm(v)))
```

So, to get the angles of the projections on the the first $N-1$ axes, let's say, you could do something like this:

```
v = b-a;

for i = 1:N-1        

    angles(i) = acos(v(i)/norm(v));

end
```

Or, if you want to skip the for loop,

```
angles = acos(v/norm(v));
```